# How to set the world bounds in Phaser framework to circle

Tags: phaser-framework

In Phaser framework I can set the world bounds by using:

```
this.game.physics.p2.setBounds(90, 90, 400, 400, true, true, true, true, false);
```

This will make world bounds in a rectangle shape. What I need, however, is to make a circle shaped world bounds (I have a drum in which I want the balls to "jump"). One idea I have (if more elegant solution won't be found) is to make a bunch of static objects around the image of the drum (similar to [this example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/p2-physics/static-body)) but I would like to avoid that if possible, so if someone knows how to solve this help would be appreciated.